# How to create 3.0 version HDInsight cluster by Azure command line tools?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

"azure hdinsight cluster create --help" does not appears having any option to choose specific version of HDInsight. Is there API level support?

Answer (score 1):

The command you're referencing now supports the `--version` parameter. Try it out, or view this and other parameters by running this:

```
azure hdinsight cluster create --help
```

Comment: Works perfect. But how do you choose e.g. when --version 3.5 could mean spark 1.6 or spark 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The cli can't specify version.  Can you user Windows Azure PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The value that the cli uses is hardcoded to 'default' in [hdinsightservice.js](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/hdinsight/hdinsightservice.js) in the [azure-sdk-for-node](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node).

Although not a great long-term solution, you could edit this file on your workstation.  The default install will place it at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure/lib/services/hdinsight/hdinsightservice.js`.

Change line 122 to read: `Version : '3.0'` instead of `Version : 'default'` and it should create a version 3.0 cluster.